# Visual Studio Setup Project - Include .reg file on installation

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, registry, setup-project

I'm creating an msi of a WinForms-app by using a setup-project.
One last thing I'm struggling with is adding entries in the registry.

I have to make some changes ( or create) a few entries in the register for the embedding of SAP.
The client will send me a reg-file that I have to use with the installation.

Can anyone help me out on how to achieve this?
Is it possible by using the reg-file or do I have to do it by code (custom action)?

This is the first time I have to create a setup like this, so bear with me.
I've tried to search for it, but haven't found a satisfying answer yet.
Or at least, I don't think I have...

Thanks.

Comment: It would be good to get out of the habit of using VS setup projects - they're no longer included in VS2012, so it would be worthwhile learning a different tool (e.g. Wix)

Comment: This is the first time I had to make a setup-project because there where some extra things needed (like the reg-file) and I thought that a setup-project would be the simplest solution. But next time I will certainly take a look at those tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an entire Registry section to VS Setup projects. Just select the Registry button at the top of Solution Explorer. Then, right click on the "Registry on Target Machine" node, and select "Import...".

This will open a File Open dialog, looking for `.reg` files. Select the file you've been provided and you're done.

Comment: I'm still waiting on the reg-file of the client (as usual they don't care about their own deadlines when they have to provide something theirself :-) ) but I think this will do the trick. I must say that I haven't come across a post regarding this item that explained it so simple. Thanks.

Comment: How can I ensure that the registry files will be added on installation of the project? Is this really all that is needed?